# Smooth decrease in number with acceleration or deceleration

Tags: javascript, acceleration

I have coordinates, and I need them to decrease smoothly with a slowdown in the end.
For example:
40,
20,
10,
5,
2.5,
1.25,
1.125,
0.925
and so on to ~0
The launch is quick, and the end is smooth.

I tried to use setInterval, and multiply by 0.9 each millisecond. But when it stops number is still either too much higher than the required number or too missed.

```
var friction = 5,
    frict = setInterval(function()
{
    sprite.position.x -= friction;
    if (sprite.position.x <= finishline.x)
    {
        friction *=0.9;
        if (friction < 0.05)
        {
            clearInterval(frict);
        }
    }
},5);
```

I expect the number 50 to smoothly drop to 0 in a short time and a noticeable smooth deceleration at the end.

Comment: switch to a repeating setTimeout, setInterval's interval is fixed

Comment: maybe you can inspire from css easing formulas : http://gizma.com/easing/#l

Comment: @Taki Why on earth does a CSS easing demo need flash?

Comment: @Nit i guess it's an old website that uses flash, and re-reading my comment got me thinking that `Css easing` might be misleading, as `easing` is not restricted to css, it's used in action script too,